# where() and sort() not working for populated records in sails

Tags: sorting, sails.js, waterline, populate

I created a Sails application with two models Person and Department.
They are having a one-to-one relationship.Sails-mysql is the adapter using.When I am trying to populate department details along with Person using where() or sort() criteria the resulting records are not sorted or where() is not applied.

Person.js

```
attributes: {
firstname:{
            alpha:true,
            required:true
        },
        lastname:{
            alpha:true,
            required:true
        },
        age:{
            numeric:true,
            required:true
        },
        department:{
            model:'Department'
        }
  }
```

Department.js

```
attributes: {
DepartmentName:{
        required:true,
        alpha:true
  },
  Description:{
        required:true,
        alpha:true
  },
  //relation
  person:{
      model:'Person'
  }
```

}

PersonController.js

```
Person.find().populate('department').where({DepartmentName:{"startsWith":"hr"}}).sort('Description desc').exec(console.log);
```

is not working.

I tried where() and sort() in all the possible way like

```
var sort='DepartmentName desc';
```

and pass that variable in the populate() like one below:

```
Person.find().populate('department',sort).exec(console.log);
```

but that is also not working.In the same way I tried for where() also that is also a failure.

Help me in this.

Answer (score 1):

For me this is working ;)

```
Person.find().populate('department', {
                where: {
                    DepartmentName: {
                        'startsWith': 'hr'
                    }
                },
                sort: 'DepartmentName desc'}
            ).exec(......);
```

For more information check here: http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/queries/populate
under section **Populating a collection association**